# target="_self" mysteriously changed into "_blank" on its own

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm working with php to make some web pages and I'm having a bit of struggle with a link I'm trying to make.

Basically I have my `<a>` set with target="_self" on it so that it stays on the same page. (Note the page is a new window and that I also tried using "_top" and "_parent")

```
<a href="http://ordi-003/inclusion/fiche.dos.assorti.info.php?id=<?php echo $donnees[0]['NoIdentDosAssorti'] ?>&lan=<?php echo $_SESSION['lan'] ?>" target="_self"><img src="<?php echo $donnees[0]['id2_pathImgMini'] ?>" width="75" height="75" /></a>
```

This is said link in its php form.

```
<a href="http://ordi-003/inclusion/fiche.dos.assorti.info.php?id=14&lan=fr" target="_self"><img src="../images/propriete/DosAssorti/mini/L482_mini.jpg" width="75" height="75" /></a>
```

This is the result arcoding to the browser when showing the source code.(Across IE,Firefox,Chrome)

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://ordi-003/inclusion/fiche.dos.assorti.info.php?id=14&lan=fr">
```

This is the same line according to Firebug AND the Chrome developping tools.

When clicking the linking the expected result is opening the link on the same page, however it opens it in a new window. Changing inside firebug "_blank" to "_self" and clicking the link afterwards gives the good results and opens the link on the same page.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I incorrectly using the `<a>` here?

Should I look for another way to make my link? I'm pretty open to anything really I tried different things and looked alot on google but couldn't find people with the same problem. Firefox cache is deactivated so that should not be the issue. Tried it on another computer too and it gives the same results.

If I gave too short information just tell me what I should also include as I am new to stack overflow.

Edit:I forgot to say that if I remove the target parameter and just put none, the "source code page" doesn't show anything like it should but in firefug and chrome dev tools it shows a target="_blank" still. Also just a note, there is only 1 copy of this file and it is on the localhost of the machine running the local site. I'm directly editing that file.

Edit2: http://pastebin.com/yrAMQEL9 be aware the indentation is awful on pastebin for some reason.

Comment: Why are you using a `target` at all if you want the link to load in the same window? However, your error sounds like something (a server-side script maybe?) is modifying your HTML or there is an old version cached somewhere on the server (or a proxy both machines are using) that is sent to you.

Comment: I have a feeling you looking at two completely different links...

Comment: Can you post a link? e.g. sample webpage, jsFiddle...

Comment: @ThiefMaster Well I know that target is by default _self but since it was opening in a new window I tried to force it. Firefox cache is disabled on the server and I don't know what other cache could cause that. No proxies involved.

Comment: @stevether It is the only link linking to that .php so it can't be that =/

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff It's local sorry but what is jsFiddle?

Comment: @Rayfloyd - jsFiddle is a website where you can easily type HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in a split view, and see the result on the same page. No registration is necassary, and you can easily share the result. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff How would I deal with the sql queries? I could always get the result of the execution of the php file but on one hand if I take it from the "source code page" it will be fine and if I take it from Firebug it won't. It would be representative of the problem. At best it can help you visualize how the page is made but I don't think it would be of much use. Even the link uses php to generate the next one so the link wouldn't even work.

Comment: I forgot you were using PHP - PHP won't work in jsFiddle... But you could put the result (page source) on jsFiddle and post the result.

Comment: That's the thing though the output through page source is fine and I did test it on jsFiddle and behaves like it should but when ran with php the page source and the behavior do not match. However it does match firebug who says there's a _blank. Although Scott says Firebug is not to always believe, in this case I think it's not far from truth since the behavior matches. Is there something it could "inherit" from a bit like css who would force a _blank on all <a> tags?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant piece of PHP code?

Comment: It is the first line of code on the original post the php is used to return the Id of the element I want and the $lan variable (language) all of that form the url to go to, the other piece of php used is to get the path where the image of the element is located. http://pastebin.com/yrAMQEL9 The indentation looks awful here but it might help.

Comment: Can you also paste the resulting source code on Pastebin? Also, the link tracking script (line 62 of footer.php) could cause a problem...

Comment: I'm not at the job anymore and don't have access to the code. I will come back on this next monday, I'll use @ to ring you up if that's ok with you. At the moment I really don't have access to the code

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I got some more time to try to fix this problem today. This is the output http://pastebin.com/qdVtMNHz and I commented the code you mentionned but it didn't affect anything, it didn't look used though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the replacement of my _self.

In the footer there was a script which was referenced and trough further research I found this bit of code

```
jQuery('a[href^=http]:not(.in)').attr({
    'target' : '_blank'
});
```

It caused the replacement of the _self to a _blank.

Now that I know where the problem came from I just have to check with the original coder of that function why he needed it and if it is still needed.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're running different code than the code you're editing. Make sure your changes are making it to the server you're visiting in the browser and that you're editing the right file.

Comment: The server is actually my boss computer running wamp I am editing the file directly on that computer and I am editing the good file. (I triple checked) and yes the changes are being saved I looked that too. The other computer I checked if it did the same thing was where the files are located. And the 1st line of code is the one in the .php I understand that. But the difference between line 2 and 3 is just not normal. Source code of the page tells me it's _self but Firebug tell me it's _blank at the same time. That's what I'm pretty confused about.

Comment: I've seen other people report that Firebug gives them weird stuff. Don't look at that. Look at the View Source code. There's nothing in your code that's going to swap the position of the target and href attributes.

Comment: In that case should I not trust the chrome developper tools either since it gives the same result? The view source code page gives me the good output, but the page doesn't behave like it. And there is only one copy of the file hence I cannot edit another file than  I run.

Comment: I know this is frustrating. I've been there. But there's absolutely no way the code you posted creates the output you posted. It simply doesn't. Keep checking to make sure you're editing the right file. You can insert some gibberish somewhere and make sure it shows up in the browser.

Comment: Just edited the file and my edit showed up i basically put random letters in the url and they are there but I still have the same issue unfortunatly. I might have to look for an alternative way than <a> to do this since it just doesn't want to work. This is kinda frustrating to end a day of job with a bug that just can't happen. (I'm always very badlucked on impossible bugs and whatnot) Thanks for your help anyway. I'll leave this open in case someone has another idea or have already encountered the problem. I'll be following the answers.

Comment: Is there javascript manipulating the page? Is there php after your code that could be changing the html?

Comment: the only javascript on the page is excuted on a button click and what it does is a window.open on _self and that works it is jointly used with a combobox. There are 2 other php codes under the php code discussed and they are as follow: <?php echo $donnees[$i]['NoCouleur'] about 4 times with different values so basically just returning text.

Comment: Is there anything weird in footer.php?

Comment: Mostly values output and google analytics stuff, I wasn't the one who did the footer.php http://pastebin.com/KExPKEHL